# How save MultipartFormDataContent into a file.txt?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i'm trying to save a MultipartFormDataContent in a file.txt. But I can't do it works.

this is my code:

```
MultipartFormDataContent content2 = new MultipartFormDataContent();
private async void savePhotos()
{
    string testPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath + "/file.txt";
                if (File.Exists(testPath) == false)
                {
                    File.Create(testPath);
                }
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(testPath);

                foreach (var s in content2)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(s);
                }
                tw.Close();
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
}
```

Someone knows how couild I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: as I recall from your past posts, you are getting a series of FileResults from the camera and then trying to upload them.  You want to be able to resume the upload should it fail.  Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct, because for example, if the user doesn't have  wifi. i want to be able to have the photos and upload without telling to the user. Am i clear?

Comment: *"I can't do it works"*. Explain what happens. Is there an error or exception message? Does a file get created? If it does, is it zero length, or does it contain some data?

Comment: the FileResult object you get from the camera already has all the data you need.  I would save that data, ideally to a db, but to a file if you're not ready to deal with a DB yet.  Then when you have a good connection you can use that list of FileResult objects to upload.  Once you've uploaded one you can delete the record.  Also, I would upload the images one at a time, that way if it fails you only have to resend one.  If you send them in groups you have to resend the entire group

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert it to a byte array and then save the array into the txt file. Such as:

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(testPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] buffer = getarray();// convert the MultipartFormDataContent to the byte array here
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
```